# Arduino compatible ESP32 and ESP8266 board power consumption at sleep state

Tags: esp8266, power, esp32

I have data on smaller modules with ESP32 and ESP8266, but can't find anything reliable pertaining to the whole board power consumption (current) with 12V input and microcontroller at low power or sleep state. The power subsystem on Arduino compatible boards like this one:
[image]

consists of step-down switching regulator to 5V and linear regulator to 3.3V. I wonder how this design behaves when the ESP microcontroller itself draws very small current, e.g. below 1mA. Does anyone have current measurement at DC input socket when microcontroller is in low power state without any peripherals attached to the board?

Comment: The datasheet for the regulator will tell you how it performs at different loads. And what's to stop you measuring the current yourself?

Comment: I always measure myself. Get one [usb-voltmeter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Voltmeter-Bluetooth-Multimeter-Multi-Function-Detector/dp/B07DCS11GM/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=usb+voltmeter&qid=1631196510&sr=8-6). They create wonders.

Comment: @Majenko I don't have the board. I'm asking before buying.

Comment: i would guess that's not the best board to use for low power consumption, due to usb serial, leds, etc. use a buck converter to turn 12v into 3.3v.